# Android - Trying to display bitmaps efficiently for wallpaper app which are currently 0.5MB in size each

Tags: android, eclipse, caching, memory, bitmap

Updated

I'm trying to display bitmaps efficiently for a wallpaper app which holds 50 wallpapers.

The images I'm using are each 400kb @ 1080x1920

I've researched and read I should load a scaled down version of each wallpaper into memory when the app loads instead of loading each wallpaper when it is pressed.

I've read this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap

How would I implement this using my current code? I've got here from this tutorial on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxGYGYBFrOM

Here is the updated code, ive included the whole of my MainActivity class

```
package com.example.ultimateabstractwallpaperhd;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
// Two classes you mentioned I put here.

ImageView display;
int toPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // check if next two lines are necessary
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // gets rid of app title
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11) {
           getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        }

    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    toPhone = R.drawable.one;

display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVdisplay);
ImageView one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
ImageView two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
ImageView three = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
ImageView four = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
ImageView five = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BsetWallpaper);


one.setOnClickListener(this);
two.setOnClickListener(this);
three.setOnClickListener(this);
four.setOnClickListener(this);
five.setOnClickListener(this);
setWall.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.IVimage1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
        toPhone = R.drawable.one;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
        toPhone = R.drawable.two;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
        toPhone = R.drawable.three;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
        toPhone = R.drawable.four;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
        toPhone = R.drawable.five;
        break;

    case R.id.BsetWallpaper:
        InputStream yeaaaa  = getResources().openRawResource(toPhone);

        Bitmap whatever = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.IVimage1, 1080, 1500)

        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(whatever);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

}

**EDIT:**

Ok, my resources are in the drawable-hpdi folder.

I've still got a few errors, which eclipse has flagged. I've put them in bold.

1)

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(**Resources** res, int resId,
int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
```

Eclipse explanation: Says resource cannot be resolved into a type

2)

```
int resId = getResources().**getIdentifier**(R.drawable.one, "drawable", getPackageName());
        Bitmap whatever = **decodeSampledBitmapFromResource**(getResources(), R.id.IVimage1, 1080, 1500);
```

Eclipse explanation:

Method getIdentifier not applicable for arguments list (Sorry if I've simple referenced the drawable incorrectly)

Method decodeSampledBitmapFromResource from the type MainActivity refers to the missing type resources.

Thanks so much for your help so far, it's fantastic to get such quick responses.

EDIT

Name of resource/s: Multiple Resources, named one, two, three, four, five, all with jpg extensions.

Location of resource/s: 
res/drawable-hdpi/one.jpg
res/drawable-hdpi/two.jpg
..
res/drawable-hdpi/two.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternate answer:

```
InputStream yeaaaa  = getResources().openRawResource(toPhone)
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2; \\1 would be the full resolution, 2 is half the size, 4 a quarter etc..
Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

Comment: Ah! It worked perfectly. I hate to say it but I didn't ask the correct question. Currently the wonderful help you've given me means that after the wallpaper is set, it is displayed at (1/x)* the original resolution. What I should've asked is how to display the images in the app at lower resolution and how to do that efficiently (like loading all the images at startup) so there is no lag when using the app. I apologise for not being direct in that respect. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: ?? "What I should"??  should what?

Comment: you should look into moving the decoding of the image to an AsyncTask:  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html to help free up the UI of your app. the answer above shows you how to downsample already.. inSampleSize.  please upvote my answers and accept one as the answer.  I work for rep points :)

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the documention you mentioned, you want to create these 2 methods in your class:

```
   public static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

then instead of :

```
Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yeaaaa);
```

use

```
Bitmap whatever = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), resourceID, width, height)
```

don't put the resource in raw put it in your drawables folder so you can use the resource ID

you can get the resourceID like so:

```
getResources().getIdentifier([what ever your named your drawable] , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

**EDIT**

per your ajusted code a few things to take note of..

it looks like you are passing the ImageView not the actual resource of a Bitmap..

this line:

```
 Bitmap whatever = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.IVimage1, 1080, 1500)
```

should be:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier([what ever your named your drawable] , "drawable", getPackageName());

 Bitmap whatever = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), resId, 1080, 1500)
```

Comment: Ah okay, now the thing is because I've got this code (below) the resourceID changes each time the image is pressed.

Comment: i added a line of code to my answer on how to get the resource id from the drawable folder

Comment: Ah okay, now the thing is because I've got this code (below) the resourceID changes each time the image is pressed. (this) is the variable I'm using to change it. Also, I'm getting an error saying that resources cannot be resolved into a type. Thanks for your quick reply!! It's much appreciated.

Comment: can you update your code so i can make better sense of what you are saying

Comment: Added your suggestions, but still not working properly.

Comment: Please include the name of your resource and where it is saved in your project

Comment: I posted a possible simpler answer